# Twisting sheaf is invertible.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a small question in the proof of Hartshorne's book of the fact that $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is locally free. The thing is that it suffices to prove that

$$ \mathcal{O}(1)(D^{+}(f)) \cong \mathcal{O}(D^{+}(f))$$

in order to show that
$$\mathcal{O}(1)|_{D^{+}(f)} \cong \mathcal{O}|_{D^{+}(f)}$$

What happens in the case of an open $U \subset D^{+}(f)$?

Comment: It's okay to just check the sections of an affine cover because the two sheaves are quasicoherent. (Coherent, even, if you're working over a noetherian base.)

Answer (score 1):

Since $D_{+}(f)=\mathrm{Spec}S_{(f)}$ is an affine scheme and both sheaves are quasi-coherent (as pointed out by Hoot in the comments), Hartshorne uses in this proof that for affine schemes $X=\mathrm{Spec}A$ the functor

$$ M \mapsto \tilde{M} $$

(where $\tilde{M}$ is the sheaf associated to $M$ as described in the same book, sending an open subset $U$ of $X$ to the module of sections of the projection $\sqcup_{\mathfrak{p}\in U} M_{\mathfrak{p}} \to U$ which locally look like fractions $\frac{m}{f}$ with $m\in M$ and $f\in A$) induces an equivalence of categories between $A$-modules and quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-modules with inverse the functor "taking global sections":

$$ \mathcal{M} \mapsto \mathcal{M}(X) $$

Thus the isomorphism between the global sections gives us the desired natural isomorphism between the sheaves of modules.